# How to make import from syntax work with electron and typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, electron

I'm starting a new project with electron and typescript, I set up the project and got a basic hello world running, however I tried to add a library (https://github.com/benjamn/recast), the import syntax is not working.

```
import React from 'react'; // Works
import { parse, prettyPrint } from 'recast'; // Does not work, cannot read property parse of undefined
import tsParser from 'recast/parsers/typescript'; // Does not work
// const recast = require('recast'); // Works
// const tsParser = require('recast/parsers/typescript'); // Works
```

My webpack config and tsconfig are the following:

webpack.rules.js:

```
module.exports = [
  // Add support for native node modules
  {
    test: /\.node$/,
    use: "node-loader"
  },
  {
    test: /\.(m?js|node)$/,
    parser: { amd: false },
    use: {
      loader: "@marshallofsound/webpack-asset-relocator-loader",
      options: {
        outputAssetBase: "native_modules"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    test: /\.tsx?$/,
    exclude: /(node_modules|.webpack)/,
    loaders: [
      {
        loader: "ts-loader",
        options: {
          transpileOnly: true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

webpack.renderer.config.js:

```
const rules = require("./webpack.rules");
const plugins = require("./webpack.plugins");
const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require("tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin");

rules.push({
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: [{ loader: "style-loader" }, { loader: "css-loader" }]
});

module.exports = {
  // Put your normal webpack config below here
  module: {
    rules
  },
  resolve: {
    // Add `.ts` and `.tsx` as a resolvable extension.
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"],
    plugins: [
      new TsconfigPathsPlugin({
        /*configFile: "./path/to/tsconfig.json" */
      })
    ]
  },
  plugins: plugins
};
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "baseUrl": "src/"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm in a similar situation, and getting nowhere fast.

Comment: you need to use a combination of typescript (setting base url) and babel-module-resolver, that is how I make it work on my current projects anyways, send me an email to ospfranco@protonmail.com, I will create a small tutorial on my blog later

Comment: thanks for the willingness to help. Truth be told, I think I figured out my issue. Cheers!